# How to differentiate between Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessors 7120P, 7120X, 7120D, 7120A

Tags: hpc, intel-mic, xeon-phi

I have a Xeon phi coprocessor 7120P.
When i run micinfo, i see board SKU to be C0PRQ-7120 P/A/X/D.
I notice that the SMC HW Revision states Product 300W Passive CS and i read on tomshardware that P stands for passive cooling for the intel xeon phi familiy devices.
Is this it or is there any other way to tell which device i have on my system 7120 P/A/X or D?

From the specs given on ark.intel.com, all four devices appear to be same.
Can some one elaborate on what are the actual differences between these devices.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The A/P/X/D variants of the Intel Xeon Phi Coprocessor 7120 are different form factors with different cooling.  The codes are: A = active, that is, with fan; P = passive, that is, air stream needs to be supplied from chassis fans; D = dense, special form factor for very dense design; X is a special form factor for manufacturers that want to make their individual designs.

The CPU and memory of these coprocessor versions is the same in all four cases.

Cheers,
        -michael